# Hide field rows when viewing a Laravel Nova Model

Tags: laravel

Is it possible to hide specific rows when viewing a model in Nova?

Let's say I have a bunch of Users and Companies. A User can own one or more Companies and should be able to view and edit them. But I don't want the other users to be able to see companies that they don't own.

I managed to remove the ability to edit, delete and see the name of a company if you don't own it but I can't seem to remove the companies from the list properly. [(ScreenShot)](https://i.gyazo.com/6b9265c92d1e19b3be8ce965a828cd6e.png)

Is this even possible yet? Or do you have a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

From [the manual](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/resources/fields.html#showing-hiding-fields):

You can use these methods on each field:

```
hideFromIndex
hideFromDetail
hideWhenCreating
hideWhenUpdating
onlyOnIndex
onlyOnDetail
onlyOnForms
exceptOnForms
```

Example:

```
Text::make('Name')->hideFromIndex()
```

Comment: these are for fields, not for row